# lua : is declaring a table to 'host' all the graphic elements a bad practice?

Tags: object, lua, lua-table

i never learnt 'academic' coding, so i hope my question is not stupid.

To fix the problem of local/global declaration of variables, i took the habit to create a local table at the beginning of a file to host all the future objects:

```
local g = {} 
g.myRectangle = display.newRect(...)
g.myImage = display.newImg(...)
```

Is that a bad practice? I suspect it slows down the overall applications, but I am not sure. After all, all my variables are `local`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [codereview.se]

Comment: It may also get closed as _primarily opinion-based_ question. You need to provide more information or ask a specific question (for eg. in terms of performance etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a semantic diference between your code and

```
local gMyRectangle = display.newRect(...)
local gMyImage = display.newImg(...)
```

as long your use case don't go further. With your way you might pass the table to a function and this will have less parameter (you will pass the whole with one reference). But as they are all global, there is probably no need to pass to a function.

It might have influence on the performance as a (additional) table lookup is necessary on access the variable. Depends on how much objects are in the table. (Read further here http://lua-users.org/wiki/OptimisationCodingTips).

Comment: Globals span across every file, while a `local g` table would only be visible to the file it was declared in.